# Flutter column layout

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I have a column with two children 'text field and grid view' and have this huge space in between that I can't get rid of it.

This is the code

```
SafeArea(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          child: TextField(
            readOnly: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: GridView.count(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          children: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the first Expanded widget and keep it's children, i.e. the Container

```
SafeArea(
child: Column(
    children: [
       Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          ),
          child: TextField(
            readOnly: true,
          ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: GridView.count(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          children: []
```